# Why do i get different Query result on PHP App and PhpMyAdmin? what is proper way to do strict/normal search?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have request that works well on PhpMyAdmin but doesn't show same result on my PHP application.

my Table looks like this:

```
 table_one
id| title
1 | title 01
2 | title 02
3 | title 03
etc.. <= 11
```

**id** is INT and **title** is VARCHAR(50)

**Request A** (strict):

```
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE title LIKE 'title 01'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE title = 'title 01'
```

- result on PhpMyAdmin `1 | title 01`
- result on PHP App `(nothing)`

it should display only title 01 values and nothing else

**Request B** (non strict):

```
SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE title LIKE '%title 01%'
```

- result on PhpMyAdmin `1 | title 01`
- result on PHP App  `all values from 0 <=10 (does not display 11)`

if i will request *title 0* it should display all titles that start with title 0 like 01 02 03 04 etc <= 09 (i think this command is '%title 01' but its not working)

my php code is like this:

```
switch($Request){
    case 'A': $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE title LIKE 'title 01'"); break;
    case 'B': $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE title LIKE '%title 01%'"); break;
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    for($i=0; $i<(count($row)/2); $i++)
    {
        echo " " . $row[$i] . " ";
    }
}
```

it works well on PhpMyAdmin but doesn't work properly on my PHP Application.

what am i missing?

i need some kind of **strict**/**non strict** search:

1. in **STRICT** mode, when i write **title 01** it should display only values which's title **is** title 1  instead of full table.
2. in **non Strict** mode (normal) when i write title 01 it should display any values which's title **contains** title 01

Comment: can we have some sample source data please

Comment: Table above shows what data i have. I have IDs from 1 to 11 (1,2,3...10,11) and i have titles with same numbers in them (title 01, title 02... title 10, title 11)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Anyway, see this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8b2f4bbab1790724cee2f93da2d5370 - all your queries appear to return the same result.

Comment: I can't see all of the context in which the various PHP queries run but I can't see any obvious reason why they could be different, unless it's something silly like PHP is pointing at a different copy of the database, which has different data in it.

Comment: That’s right! But the problem is that, in my Php web app, results are not same. I send request with exactly same queries that i wrote here but get different results... (as show in question)

Comment: You've only shown the PHP context for two of the 4 queries you mentioned, but assuming they're done the same way, then the only reasons for that could be a) you're not running the query you think you are, or b) PHP is not looking at the data you think it is. Have you checked both of these things? The way you're outputting the data should show the results correctly, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: P.S. `if i will request title 0 it should display all titles that start with title 0 like 01 02 03 04 etc <= 09 (i think this command is '%title 01' but its not working)` ...no, the command for that would be `LIKE 'title 0%'`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=170ae14af38dd0e48ce6d3b9cb5a82bc

Comment: Yes i did. Im not total newbie in php or sql. I never had this kind of issue before. I mean when i send: LIKE ‘%title 01%’ i get display of values 1-10 (containing 10), and as you see i should get only title 01. It looks like this request “LIKE ‘%title 01%’” looks for ‘title’ and ‘01’ not for ‘title 01’. Im sure that database is correct, it has only one table (because its TEST database)

Comment: Are those UTF-8 quote marks (`‘` instead of `'`) really in your PHP code, or just a result of copying your code into StackOverflow?

Comment: No no its just because of device im currently replying with. (iPhone)

Comment: It's literally impossible for `LIKE 'title 01%'` to return `title 02` or `title 03` or any of the others. We can see that from the dbFiddle, and you have seen it in your own phpMyAdmin output. SQL does not return different results depending on whether you connect to it with PHPMyAdmin or some other script. Something in your PHP code is the problem, but the example you've given above doesn't make clear what it is (unless perhaps the snippet is incomplete - where is `$Request` coming from for instance?

Comment: $Result is simple variable for example switch (modded code for simplifying question) that displays Results that are given in question. Okay ill recheck everything again and will update question if ill find anything different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fix:**

seems that when i was passing variables to header it was adding %20 instead of whitespace, so request was wrong.
so i fixed it by adding (:space:) instead of whitespace and parsing it again, replacing all (:space:) with actual whitespace before sending request.